# MS Access 2007 in Wine: hyperlinks couldn't be opened

Tags: microsoft-office, wine, hyperlink, microsoft-access-2007

I need to set up a machine with Linux (Ubuntu or Mint) and install MS Access on it using wine (MS Office programs that I worked with before, Word and Excel, worked in wine just fine).

But I'm facing unexpected problems: user can't follow the `http://` hyperlink, for example http://google.com : when user clicks on it, access just shows dialog window:

> microsoft office access can't follow the hyperlink

I tried to follow the hyperlink in MS Word and Excel, in both of them it works (when user clicks on a hyperlink, native linux firefox is opened with the given link, everything works nice)

I tried both Wine 1.6 and 1.7, result is the same.

I tried to check it with `strace`, as follows:

```
strace -ff -o trace wine /home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/Office12/MSACCESS.EXE
```

then I've reproduced the problem with non-opening hyperlink http://google.com, closed MS Access, `grep`-ped across the trace files for `google`, `hyperlink`, nothing is found. Wine's own output is not useful, too (no special message is generated when user clicks a hyperlink)

Does anyone have some idea what could I try to make it work?